# AddLookup using the client object model?

Tags: client-object-model, lookup-column, addfieldasxml

Trying (desperately) to find the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client equivalent of 
SPList.Fields.Addlookup

My code:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/");
Web website = ctx.Web;
ListCreationInformation ci = new ListCreationInformation();
ci.Title = "MyList";
ci.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList; 
List lst = website.Lists.Add(ci);
lst.AddLookup // <- THIS DOES NOT EXIST
lst.Fields.AddLookup // <- NOR DOES THIS
```

I've tried using AddFieldAsXml with every conceivable combination of attributes/values - no luck

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new instance of the [FieldLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlookup.aspx) object and then use

```
FieldLookup myLookupField;
//Configuration of Field Stuff
lst.Fields.Add(myLookupField);
```

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately you can't new up a LookupField without knowing the 'object path' - the signature is FieldLookup fld = new FieldLookup([ClientRuntimeContext Context], [ObjectPath ObjectPath]);                   There's no documentation on the constructor - it seems that MS has reservered it for internal use - (mind you, if there IS another way to create the Lookfield , please let me know)